# How to project new images into ICA space?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, signal-processing

I'm using the [FastICA MATLAB toolbox](http://research.ics.aalto.fi/ica/fastica/code/dlcode.shtml)

My training image are in `tImage` where each row is one observation. The matrix is 30x35200, 30 face images with 35200 feature length (Pixels).

When I run `[icasig, A, W] = fastICA(tImage)`, the output `icasig` is 30x35200, `A` is 30x30 and `W` is 30x30. What I have learned is that the `icasig` are the projected images, so no further processing is required.

Now I am trying to prepare the test image and project it on `W`. My difficulty is the dimensions. My test image is 1x35200  (one image with 35200 features). How can I project it on `W` which is 30x30?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the toolbox? My first instinct is that you may need to transpose your tImage matrix, but I'd like to examine the documentation.

Comment: Sorry for late response...
I am using fastICA, link is

Comment: Sorry for late response...
I am using fastICA, link is
https://research.ics.aalto.fi/ica/fastica/code/dlcode.shtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding what the `icasig` matrix is.

**What are the outputs?**
`icasig` are the estimated independent components of `tImage`, **not** the projected rows of `tImage`. These are similar to basis vectors for your new projection space (they are not really basis vectors because they are not orthogonal, but they behave like basis vectors). We can confirm this with a couple of experiments.

First, let's use `A` to reconstruct the first image. `A` **are** the projected rows of `tImage`, often called the mixing matrix. The columns of `A` specify how much of each component contributes to each image.

(I used the [Face Recognition Project](http://courses.media.mit.edu/2004fall/mas622j/04.projects/faces/) images for my code samples)

```
figure;
subplot(1, 3, 1);
imshow(reshape(tImage(1, :), 128, 128));
title('First Image');

reconstruction = A(1, :)* icasig;
subplot(1, 3, 2);
imshow(reshape(reconstruction, 128, 128));
title('Reconstructed Image');

subplot(1, 3, 3);
imagesc(reshape(abs(tImage(1, :) - reconstruction), 128, 128));
title('Difference');
colorbar;
```

[image: Comparison of Reconstruction to Original]

You can see in the difference image that the reconstruction is an approximate version of the original, but to the human eye, the two images look identical.

Therefore, you can use `A` as a low dimensional stand in for `tImage`.

**ICA for Basis Faces**

When you visualize the rows of `icasig` as images, you are visualizing the components. You may have seen [Eigenface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenface) visualizations. These images could be considered ICAfaces.

Here's an image of the first 9

[image: ICAfaces]

These faces represent the features in which images vary the most.

**Projecting Test Images**

For the new test image, we want to figure out how much of each component to mix together for the projection. Basically, we want to know what its row in the `A` matrix would look like.

To reconstruct the first image from `A`, we did the following

```
reconstruction = A(1, :) * icasig;
```

Now, the `A` for the test image is unknown, but if we substitute the test image for the reconstruction, we can solve for `A` using a linear solver.

```
A_test = icasig' \ testImage'; %I had to transpose things so that the dimensions matched

figure;
subplot(1, 3, 1);
imshow(reshape(testImage, 128, 128));
title('Test Image');

reconstruction = A_test' * icasig;
subplot(1, 3, 2);
imshow(reshape(reconstruction, 128, 128));
title('Reconstructed Image');

subplot(1, 3, 3);
imagesc(reshape(abs(testImage - reconstruction), 128, 128));
title('Difference');
colorbar;
```

The result looks a lot like out original reconstruction results

[image: Test image reconstruction]

I used the [mldivide](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html) linear solver, but you could also use [linsolve](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linsolve.html), or whatever your favorite linear solver is.

**Why not use simple projection?**

In my first draft of this answer, I suggested projecting the test image onto `icasig`. I was thinking of how I would do the [reprojection with PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis#Dimensionality_reduction), but I'm not sure whether the same technique can be transferred to ICA because the components are not orthogonal.

In a small experiment, the results were not as good as using a linear solver. Here's the projection code I used.

```
A_test = icasig * testImage';
A_test = A_test ./ sqrt(sum(icasig.^2, 2));
```

[image: Projection comparison]

**What's W for then?**

I believe this is used for blind source separation. This is a very different application of ICA. I am not an expert at this technique, so I would suggest reading about it on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_component_analysis#Methods_for_blind_source_separation). In this article, they also use `W` to refer to a separating or unmixing matrix.

The terminology is confusing because [in PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis#Table_of_symbols_and_abbreviations) `W` is often used for the components, where `icasig` is used here.

Comment: Thank you for reply, 80% go it, but still confuse in projecting...
Can you please give example with my variables...
Thank you

Comment: Thank you for reply, 80% got it, but still confuse in projecting... Can you please give example with my variables... Thank you

Comment: @Affan I came back to finish up and provided more examples. Best of luck to you.

Comment: Thank you Cecilia,
I am also using "A_test = icasig * testImage';"  this technique for projecting the face image both train and test...

Comment: If I've satisfactorily answered your question, please accept the answer by clicking the check mark symbol next to the up/down vote arrows. Otherwise let me know where you still have doubts.